# how to calculate the p-value based on the z score of 2 independent results.

Tags: p-value

assuming I went to do fishing in lakeA for 2 weeks and manage to fish those number of fish:

23
25
24
24
25
23
27
21
22
23
18
19
22
21

I decided to move to LakeB and manage to catch the following fish in with in 17 days:

28
23
22
21
23
28
29
28
29
30
21
21
28
27
31
20
21
22

My question: how can I determine if lakeB is statistically significant than lakeA. meaning: it is better to go to lakeB because there's more fish to catch?

What I did?
I calculated the Z scode for each lake but note sure how to proceed from here. How can I calculate the p value and reject/accept my hypothesis?

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of the Mann$-$Whitney $U$ Test? If you had larger sample sizes than you may be able to get away with applying an independent samples $t$ test. The $U$ test is a non$-$parametric alternative to this $t$ test.